# When to install packages with a preseed file and when to provision packages with Packer?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, packer

So I have been busy tweaking my Packer Ubuntu Configuration for a few days.

I am busy installing Ubuntu only and reached the point where I need to install the packages that I need for my machine. The end result is to make a vagrant box with packages preinstalled on it

Currently, I put all of my package configuration in my preseed.cfg file and I do not have a provision block at the moment. My understanding is that you can install packages within the preseed.cfg or provision block (via script or something like chef)

This is the line in my `preseed.cfg` file:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string  build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) openssh-server ubuntu-minimal
```

So my question is when is it appropriate from a packer point of view to install packages via preseed.cfg and when is it appropriate to use a provisioner??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a provisioning script, I (I talk only for myself, other are welcome to put their comments) aim at 2 things:

- I install packages but not only, generally I will install with a set of configuration (so for example, I install Apache but I want to configure a virtualhost or something)
- I want cross-system script so I can re-use them to provision any server (so I try to avoid shell scripting as much as possible - and if I need to end writing shell command if I develop new provisionner module, I do it for most of linux family I could use)

After my personal use of packer/vagrant is to use packer to create minimal box so I would not even put my provisioning there (only in a case the provisioning step is taking too long and I need to create new vagrant VM instances from scratch quite often) - I put the provisioning step in vagrant and it will be run when vagrant will spin the new VM.

Going back to your question, I would use the preseed for general package that do not require configuration and are absolutely necessary for the system to work; put the rest in the provisioning